# Multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a variable array named $time. And what I want to do is to count the number of seconds where the user stayed in the certain department for example dept no 8.

```
$time = array(
  '91' => array(
      '100' => array(
           '0' =>array(
              'id' =>'15',
              'time' => '2014/05/28 00:23:26',
              'dept' => '8'
            ), 
           '1' =>array(
              'id' =>'15',
              'time' => '2014/05/28 00:25:51',
              'dept' => '8'
            ),
          '2' =>array(
              'id' =>'15',
              'time' => '2014/05/28 00:27:45',
              'dept' => '9'
           ),
         '3' =>array(
             'id' =>'15',
             'time' => '2014/05/28 00:28:01',
             'dept' => '8'
          )
         '4' =>array(
             'id' =>'15',
             'time' => '2014/05/28 00:30:46',
             'dept' => '4'
          )
    )
);
```

I have the following table:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6phW.png)

23:26 to 25:51 has a 145 difference of seconds.

25:51 to 27:45 has a 114 difference of seconds.

28:01 to 30:46 has a 165 differenceof seconds.

So if we add them `145+ 114 + 166`. The total seconds that the user stayed in that dept is `424` seconds.

And in dept 9:
27:45 to 28:01 has a 16 difference of seconds.

I want to achieve the output of:

```
 $results = array(
           '8' => '424',
           '9' => '16'
 );
```

It driving me crazy. Can someone help me how to achive it or what is the best way to implement it. I tried the :

```
$timeFirst  = strtotime('2016/05/26 00:27:45');
$timeSecond = strtotime('2016/05/26 00:28:01');
$differenceInSeconds = $timeSecond - $timeFirst;
print_r($differenceInSeconds);
```

But the problem is I can't proceed because I don't have any idea how to continue it. Thank you.

Comment: You should take a look on [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference). Carbon saved many many minutes of my life. In your case you could work with $date1->diffInSeconds($date2) to get the mentioned result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that your arrays are deeply nested, so you need a few `foreach` loops to get to the details:

```
foreach($time as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $visits) {
        foreach($visits as $i => $visit) {
            if ($i == count($visits)-1) break;
            $results[$visit['dept']] += 
                strtotime($visits[$i+1]['time']) - strtotime($visit['time']);
        }
    }
}
```

`$results` is:

```
Array
(
    [8] => 424
    [9] => 16
)
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/587493).

Comment: thank you. I will check it. And if does work. I'd acccept  your answer.

Comment: when I change the key [0,1,2,3,4] the computing of seconds does not work well. Why is that happen https://eval.in/590986

Comment: (1) That is different code you have there. You have added a nested loop that goes over the same elements as the previous one. I don't understand why you do that. (2) The code I provided was based on an indexed array (as in your question), not an associative array, which is what you get when you set the keys differently. If you want that, I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: Hello trincot. I change my array keys because the data has been change. I tried to update the code you given but the results I get is not right. I declared array_keys as equivalent to the $i that you declared but is does not work at all. Please help me again :'( I asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906637/counting-seconds-between-date-array-in-php

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
function arr2timespent($arr){
  $ret=array();
  for($i=0;$i<count($arr)-1;$i++){
    $startTime=strtotime($arr[$i]["time"]);
    $endTime=strtotime($arr[$i+1]["time"]);
    $diff=$endTime-$startTime;
    $ret[$arr[$i]["dept"]]+=$diff;
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

It iterates over all entries in the array (except the last). It then takes the time-difference and adds that to the *dept-th* array entry.
This function should be called as `arr2timespent($time["91"]["100"]);`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Let me try it.