# Counting seconds between date array in php

Tags: php, arrays

This is driving me crazy. And what I want to do is to count the number of seconds where the user stayed in the certain department for example dept no 8.

I have this array:

```
$time = array(
  '91' => array(
       '100' => array(
            '2014/05/28 00:23:26' =>array(
               'id' =>'15',
               'time' => '2014/05/28 00:23:26',
               'dept' => '8'
              ), 
            '2014/05/28 00:25:51' =>array(
              'id' =>'15',
              'time' => '2014/05/28 00:25:51',
              'dept' => '8'
             ),
            '2014/05/28 00:27:45' =>array(
              'id' =>'15',
              'time' => '2014/05/28 00:27:45',
              'dept' => '9'
             ),
           '2014/05/28 00:28:01' =>array(
              'id' =>'15',
              'time' => '2014/05/28 00:28:01',
              'dept' => '8'
            ),
          '2014/05/28 00:30:46' =>array(
             'id' =>'15',
              'time' => '2014/05/28 00:30:46',
              'dept' => '4'
         )
      )
   )
);
```

The explanation is:

23:26 to 25:51 has a 145 difference of seconds.

25:51 to 27:45 has a 114 difference of seconds.

28:01 to 30:46 has a 165 differenceof seconds.

So if we add them 145+ 114 + 166. The total seconds that the user stayed in that dept is 424 seconds.

And in dept 9: 27:45 to 28:01 has a 16 difference of seconds.

I want to achieve the output of based on that array:

```
$results = array(
       '8' => '424',
       '9' => '16'
);
```

The codes I've done so far is in: https://eval.in/591599
I get some wrong results. Please some help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variant of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37772654/5459839), which will work for associative arrays, like you have here:

```
foreach($time as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $visits) {
        $visits = array_values($visits); // convert to indexed array
        foreach($visits as $i => $visit) {
            if ($i == count($visits)-1) break;
            $dept = $visit['dept'];
            $results[$dept] = (isset($results[$dept]) ? $results[$dept] : 0) +
                strtotime($visits[$i+1]['time']) - strtotime($visit['time']);
        }
    }
}
```

`$results` is:

```
Array
(
    [8] => 424
    [9] => 16
)
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/591667)